# Impala query for shell variable through command line

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I am running a impala query in while loop and for that I have created one separate query file and I am calling it from my shell script My question is ,
Can we pass shell variable matching with impala query in query file .

```
  A="INSERT_SBP_ME_VS_ME_INCOME_LAST_THIRTY_DAYS_Q"${Count}
  echo "value of A is $A"
            source ${SBP2_MNY_IN_LAST_THIRTY_DAYS_QF}
${IMPALA_CON}  -q "${${A}}"

 A value is like INSERT_SBP_ME_VS_ME_INCOME_LAST_THIRTY_DAYS_Q1 (as count is 1)

 I am doing this in this way but getting bad substitution error and I also tried 
   ${IMPALA_CON}  -q "${A}" but not getting any successful result
```

Comment: which shell you are using bash or something else ?

Comment: @RamPrasadG I am using Bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.
Here is a sample how you could have a parameterized query stored in a file
 
Which could be executed through impala-shell

```
$ cat test.sql
select 10 + ${x};
$ export x=15
$ echo "${x}"
15
$ query=`eval "echo \"$(<test.sql)\""`
$ impala-shell <connection> -q "$query"
```